# visual studio issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, keyboard

Q:

I have the following problem :

i don't know what the problem i made, but the visual studio sound strange,, arrows in the the side  of the .cs page and when type tab, dots appeared on the page ..many keys type other letters.

i reset my visual studio through import and export , reset keyboard shortcuts in the visual studio and restart my visual studio b ut still the same problem.

Comment: Do you use any extensions? Can you please provide screenshots of any visible issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try going to:

Edit > Advanced > View White Space

If it's turned on it'll show tabs as arrows and spaces as dots.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have View WhiteSpace switched on:

```
Edit -> Advanced -> Decheck View Whitepace
```

Ctrl + E, S works too